# Отцентрировать модальное окно

Tags: css, javascript

ПО этой теме много вариантов решения

Вот столкнулся с такой проблемой

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fade">Заказать звонок</a>

<!--modal-->
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
   <p>Содержимое модального окна</p>                        
   <a class="close-reveal-modal" title="Закрыть"><span>X</span></a>
</div>

.reveal-modal-bg { 
    position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
    z-index: 150;
    display: none;  
}   
.reveal-modal{      
    visibility: hidden; 
    position: fixed; top: 150px; left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -159px;
    width: 318px;   
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
    z-index: 151;   
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    border: none;   
    text-align: center;  
}
```

Все вроде нормально работает. Но при не большой прокрутке и клике на кнопку вызова модального окна - центровка окна пропадает. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема

http://szsi.com.ua/page/page20/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема у тебя в JS коде, чем ниже тем больше отступ от топа, откроешь JS увидишь сразу.

Comment: я использую плагин

Comment: Да ладно? Исправьте.

Comment: if(options.animation == "fade") {
      modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
      modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
      modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
       "opacity" : 1
      }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());     
     }

Comment: $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure

Comment: topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top'))

Comment: Так сложно? $(document).scrollTop() + topMeasure - в вашем случае 150px, чем ниже уходишь в низ, тем более будет прибавляться и тем ниже будет опускаться окно. То есть нужно сделать вместо '$(document).scrollTop() + topMeasure' 'topMeasure' и тогда вы будете получать высоту только вытащенную из CSS.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!